# How to update dynamically HtmlButton class name

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

The following code shows my Page_load function where I create a variable number of HtmlButton.

```cs
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  ...
  foreach () {
   ...
   HtmlButton myHtmlButton = new HtmlButton();
   HtmlButton.Attributes["class"] = "test";
   updatePanel1.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(myHtmlButton);
  }
  ...
}
```

Now, when I press one button, the following function is executed, and I want to change the class name of all the HtmlButtons within updatePanel1 to "test-2".

```cs
public void ChangeClass(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

I have tested in a foreach using Page.Controls and checking when I get a HtmlButton but never get one.

Thanks you.

Comment: try inspecting `sender` variable in your `ChangeClass` it should be the button.

Comment: _"I have tested in a foreach using Page.Controls and checking when I get a HtmlButton but never get one"_ I don't understand this. What is the problem?

Comment: Why you don't change the class at client-side? For example with jQuery: `$(".class").click(function() {
                $(this).removeClass('class').addClass('test-2');
                return false;
            })`

Comment: Rafal, that's not the solution, because I want to change all the class names of the buttons. And I can't change in client-side because when I press the button, there are a postback..

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to cast the `sender` back to a button and change the attribute.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    HtmlButton myHtmlButton = new HtmlButton();
    myHtmlButton.Attributes["class"] = "test";
    myHtmlButton.InnerText = "Button " + i;

    //bind the method to the html button
    myHtmlButton.ServerClick += ChangeClass;

    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(myHtmlButton);
}
```

And then the ChangeClass method

```
private void ChangeClass(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HtmlButton myHtmlButton = sender as HtmlButton;

    if (myHtmlButton.Attributes["class"] == "test")
    {
        myHtmlButton.Attributes["class"] = "test1";
    }
    else
    {
        myHtmlButton.Attributes["class"] = "test";
    }
}
```